# Dynamic Listview opens a Dynamic ListView

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, android-studio, android-fragments

I have a main activity which has a listview and a Fab by which user adds new things to the list view then after clicking the dynamically added listview the user can add more elements into the inner listview.
Think of an app like which has blank initial then a person adds two three countries clicks on a country then he can states/cities to it in a dynamical list view how do i achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a normal situation later I realized it. The first `listview` retrieves all the countries from the data base and you can add it to the databases too. Then touching on the `listview` gives set on item click listener then that particular list can be easily taken from the list. This list now contains all from that particular database.